RabbitMQ Memory Threshold Reached: Is it possible to redirect publishers to a different node instead of throttling?
According to this page  RabbitMQ will throttle publishers if the memory high watermark (or threshold) is reached.

... it raises a memory alarm and will block all connections that are publishing messages. Once the memory alarm has cleared ... normal service resumes.

In practice, it could be the case that the current node in the cluster has high memory usage, but other nodes in the cluster have less memory usage and could easily handle the load.
Throttling a publisher can be (and in my software's case is) harmful to normal operation.
Instead of throttling publishers that are connected to the node with high memory usage, is it possible to configure Rabbitmq to tell publishers to disconnect from the current node and re-connect to a different node in the Rabbitmq cluster?
